# why delete rootProject.buildDir task in gradle removed the build directory in the module

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

when I create a new android project in android studio, in the root directory of the project, the build.gradle file has a task like that:

```
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I run the task in the terminal using "gradlew clean" command, while I found the build directory in the project root directory has been deleted and the build directory in the module has also been deleted too, why? I mean the rootProject.buildDir should not include the build directory in the module

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command `gradlew clean` does not only execute the `clean` task of your root project, but the `clean` task of any project in the build.

Both the Android plugin and the Java plugin already provide a `clean` task, that deletes the build directory.

For the root project no such plugin is applied, that is why a task is added manually.